# Cookie questions in Java

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

How do I differentiate between multiple cookies set through my site? I am setting two kinds of cookies one to see if the user has visited the site or not and an other one for authentication. How do I differentiate between these two? I get both of them when someone accesses a page after authentication. Do I add extra information to the Cookie Value or is there some other way? I understand the setName() function will change the name (from jsessionid) for every cookie from then on. Am I correct?

- Pav

Comment: yes (15 chars). Didn't you try it?

Comment: I assume you are talking about setName(). I could not try it since my IDE env somehow is not seeing it. I import java.lang.String as per this http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/SessionCookieConfig.html#setName%28java.lang.String%29 but its not seeing it and so I thought there is something wrong with what I am trying to do

Comment: Never mind. I forgot that the name goes into the constructor of the class.

Comment: As far as jsessionid it will not change. (unless you explicitly change that cookie). jsessionid is used to maintain a session between the browser and the server. Do not use it. assume it is for the app server use only.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless, to authenticate an user, I'd rather use the `HttpSession` instead. On login, put the `User` object as a session attribute so that you can just check the presence of the `User` object in the session. The `HttpSession` itself is backed by the `JSESSIONID` cookie, the only difference is that the servletcontainer will manage this all for you transparently.

Comment: JSESSIONID is not enough isn't it? I need to differentiate between different cookies and the only way to do that is by setting the name of the cookie per functionality.

Comment: You should not touch the JSESSIONID cookie in any way. It's used to maintain the server side `HttpSession`. For the "visited" cookie, just create your own cookie as you already did. To differentiate it on every request, just loop through `request.getCookies()` and check its name.

Comment: Yes. That is correct. I realized that but the main problem with my code as I debug it now is that the cookie I am setting with addCookie is not reaching the browser. I misunderstood it and thought the name is not getting set when in fact the cookie itself is not reaching the browser.  

The only fields I set in the cookie are the name, domain and value. I do not see it in the browser somehow. Any guesses on why this could be happening?

Comment: Maybe you're looking at the wrong response?  How are you checking this all? I've found [Firebug](http://getfirebug) plugin for Firefox very useful in this all.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong question. Cookie name is set when the cookie object is created.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this site for a cookie tutorial http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Cookies.html

You should be able to do a getName and check the name for the cookie. Here is a sample

```
  public static String getCookieValue(Cookie[] cookies,
                                      String cookieName,
                                      String defaultValue) {
    for(int i=0; i<cookies.length; i++) {
      Cookie cookie = cookies[i];
      if (cookieName.equals(cookie.getName()))
        return(cookie.getValue());
    }
    return(defaultValue);
  }
```

You shoud create the cookie with something like this ...

```
Cookie searchStringCookie =
  new LongLivedCookie("name", value);
response.addCookie(searchStringCookie);
```

Comment: Thanks. I saw that and am getting there.

Comment: Guys.. response.addCookie() is not setting the cookie in the browser. Any pointers on why this could be? The only fields I set in the cookie are the name, domain and value. I do not see it in the browser somehow.

Comment: @user220201 Are cookies turned off ?

Comment: No. Cookies are not turned off. I am seeing some JSESSIONID cookie in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Cookie is [constructed](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#Cookie(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) as a name-value pair.

The [getCookies()](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getCookies()) call of [HttpServletRequest](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) interface will return all the cookies in the request at hand.

You can iterate over all the cookies and find your requred cookie by checking the name using the [getName](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#getName()) call of the [Cookie](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html) and [retrieve it's value](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#getValue()).